# Session error on symfony2.1

Tags: php, symfony, apache2

I will try to describe my situation,
I have a localhost development server with lamp configuration.

- ubuntu
- apache2
- mysql5.1
- php5

I am using Symfony2.1 to develop a login form. It runs on top of Xampp.

I also have a testing environment on Amazon EC2 cloud with a similar configuration

- ubuntu
- apache2
- mysql5.1
- php5
- same Symfony2.1 environment

When I am using login form on my localhost it is sending my credentials to the database and I get logged in.

When I am using login form on my Testing environment I am getting an error :

> Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
>   in /var/www/einstein/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 183

I am using Symfony2 Session mechanism to store login credentials.
I noticed that setting csrf protection to false in config.yml prevent this error from appearing.

Any directions I might choose to investigate ?

Comment: `session.autostart` is turned off in your php.ini?

Comment: similar question check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12431067/430112)

Comment: Also, to make sure this doesn't happen on your localhost too, just make sure that you actually show notices in your error_reporting clause on php.ini

Comment: Tried session.autostart option  ... it did not help me at all ..

Comment: What i noticed is that apache 2.2 is not supporting mod_session , I might have to install apache 2.4.x

Comment: Ok , I have solved the problem when I compiled Apache 2.4.4 with php 5.4.12. Make sure that you use same directories when compiling  ...